# Implementing a generic and dynamic facade for python classes

Tags: python, python-3.x, facade

I wanted to implement a sort of facade pattern in python. However because I need to do the same for all methods, I'd like to do it in a generic way. Let me use an example:

```py
class MyObject:

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # do something with args/kwargs

    def method1(self, x):
        # do something

    def method2(self, x, a):
        # do something

    def method3(self, x, a, b):
        # do something


class MyFacade:

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.x = SOMETHING
        self.obj = MyObject(*args, **kwargs)

    def method1(self):
        return self.obj.method1(self.x)

    def method2(self, a):
        return self.obj.method2(self.x, a)

    def method3(self, a, b):
        return self.obj.method3(self.x, a, b)
```

Now because I have several classes like MyObject, I'd like a generic way of creating a MyFacade for each of them without having to write code for each method (they all do more or less the same). Also if MyObject changes, I'd like MyFacade not being impacted and rather handle any interface change in MyObject  transparently.

Thanks for the help!

---

**EDIT:**

This works but methods inherited from MyInterface raise TypeError because of the extra argument.

```py
class MyObject:

    def method1(self, x):
        print(x)

    def method2(self, x, a):
        print(x, a)

    def method3(self, x, a, b):
        print(x, a, b)


class MyInterface:

    def methodX(self):
        print("YAY!")



class MyFacade(MyInterface, MyObject):

    def __init__(self):
        self.x= "WHATEVER"

    def __getattribute__(self, item):
        result = super().__getattribute__(item)
        if callable(result):
            return lambda *args, **kwargs: result(self.x, *args, **kwargs)
        return result
```

---

**EDIT:**

I modified condition this way and now problem with MyInterface is gone:

```py
if callable(result) and result.__name__ in MyObject.__dict__:
```

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getattr__ - sorry don't have more time but that should get you on the right track

Comment: Can you clarify what you are trying to do? The purpose of the Facade Pattern is to *change* the outwards appearance of the wrapped object. With the current setup, why not *inherit* ``MyFacade`` from ``MyObject`` and add the attribute ``x``?

Comment: I'm creating an adapter for a new library that I'm integrating into the system as a replacement for an old one.. MyObject is an object from new library. MyFacade instead wants to expose to the system the required interface. The system can't pass the x argument, however I can initialize MyFacade in such a way it's able to "inject" the x argument with a proper value at every function call toward MyObject. I'm not sure if this clarified or actually created more confusion :D

Answer (score 0):

The obvious way of doing this is to use the fact that class and function names are variables and can be assigned so MyFacade could be defined as follows:

```
class MyFacade:

    def __init__(self,obj, *args, **kwargs):
        self.x = SOMETHING
        self.obj = obj(*args, **kwargs)

    def method1():
        return self.obj.method1(self.x)

    def method2(a):
        return self.obj.method2(self.x, a)

    def method3(a, b):
       return self.obj.method1(self.x, a, b)
```

and the set-up call would be eg:

```
fasc = MyFscade(MyOject,*args,**kwargs)
```

Comment: This seems to be the same code as in the question, barring that ``obj`` is passed in. The method are still manually defined, and do not change if ``obj`` changes.

Comment: This doesn't solve my issue. What happens if MyObject gets a method4() and also method2() is changed to allow 2 more arguments?